# How do I install the Windows 8 Consumer Preview?

Tags: windows-7, windows, uninstall, windows-8-preview

After downloading the Windows 8 Consumer Preview ISO image then downloading and running [download Windows 8 Consumer Preview Setup](http://goo.gl/sVnfM) I'm asked to uninstall certain programs.

I really don't want to remove these programs (among them Windows Defender, Sandboxie, Norton Internet Security...)?  What can I do about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the ISO, repartition, and install it using a USB key or cd to a separate partition, or [possibly do a VHD install](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GuideToInstallingAndBootingWindows8DeveloperPreviewOffAVHDVirtualHardDisk.aspx). I suspect the preview updates your system.

Comment: Isn't that what the preview does automatically?  How can the preview be installed within windows 7?

Comment: Well, if it is upgrading your current install (and replacing it) it makes perfect sense to complain about software you have

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing an upgrade from your current Windows?
If you do not want to remove your current version of Windows, I would suggest that you create a new partition to install Windows 8 and do a dual boot for it. Or try to install the Windows 8 in a virtual machine.

[Step by Step instructions for installing in a virtual machine](http://www.mywindowsclub.com/resources/5810-Install-Windows-Consumer-Preview-Oracle-VM.aspx)